# possible outcomes when dice are thrown?

Tags: permutations

What are the possible outcomes when a **'m' sided die is thrown 'n' times**? and 
What are the possible outcomes when **'n' dice are thrown at a time having 'm' sides each**?

Answer (score 3):

The number of outcomes for the two scenarios are precisely the same:

$$m^n\;\text{ outcomes}$$

That is, it doesn't matter whether we throw a die $n$ times, or if we throw $n$ dice all at once, as long as in both scenarios, we use the same values for $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Needs another UV +1